# How to graceful shutdown web app when it exceeds start time limit in Azure App Service?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

In `Azure App Service` I have a `ASP.NET Core` web app that can need to do a long running initialization before it starts receiving requests. The initialization can take more time than set in `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT`. When it happens `AAS` kills the app.

I want `AAS` try to gracefully stop the app via sending `SIGTERM` signal.

I've extracted all long running initialization to an implementation of `IHostedService` and use `CancellationToken`s. I tested it on a local machine via sending `SIGTERM` while this initialization was running and it gracefully shutdowned, but `AAS` stills kill the app.

It looks like `AAS` doesn't try to `SIGTERM` the app and just sends `SIGKILL`.

Comment: @DasariKamali, unfortunately I cannot share the code, but I've added details about the app implementation

Comment: The default is 230 seconds (or 4 minutes) for Linux containers and 300 seconds (or 5 minutes) for Windows containers, optimizing the initialization process of the application to complete within the allowed time limit.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure App Service does not send a SIGTERM signal to gracefully shut down a web app when it exceeds the start time limit. It terminates the process by sending a SIGKILL signal.

In Azure, by changing the App configuration it can be done.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can implement a workaround to handle graceful shutdowns when the start time limit is exceeded.

Update the Program.cs file in your ASP.NET Core web app project.
Create a static variable to track whether the application is shutting down gracefully.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static bool IsShuttingDown { get; private set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
    }
}

Modify the Main method to SetUp a SIGTERM handler.

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Program.IsShuttingDown = true;
    };

}
```

Check the `IsShuttingDown` flag to perform a graceful shutdown in `IHostedService.`

```
public class LongRunningInitializationService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<LongRunningInitializationService> _logger;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public LongRunningInitializationService(ILogger<LongRunningInitializationService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Token to check for cancellation requests
        Task.Run(() => DoInitialization(), _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task DoInitialization()
    {
        try
        {
            while (!Program.IsShuttingDown)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                _cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

           _logger.LogInformation("Initialization completed.");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
          _logger.LogWarning("Initialization canceled.");
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

If the Azure App Service exceeds the start time limit then it sends a SIGKILL signal to terminate the process.

And the SIGTERM handler in the Main method will set the `IsShuttingDown` flag, allowing the `LongRunningInitializationService` to perform a graceful shutdown by cancelling the initialization process.

> Azure App Service has a timeout mechanism, and if the shutdown process takes longer than the timeout period, it still result in a forced termination.

For more information, refer to [MS Doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/how-to-configure-health-probes-graceful-termination?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: What is the source of the first quote?

Do you suggest me to use `Azure Spring Apps` instead of `Azure App Service`? I have a **`ASP.NET Core`** application, but not a `Spring Boot` one.

And how is it even possible to handle `SIGTERM` if `SIGKILL` is sent?

Comment: Implement Graceful Shutdown: In your ASP.NET Core application, handle the SIGTERM signal explicitly using the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit event or the WebHostBuilder.ConfigureKestrel method. This allows you to perform any necessary cleanup or shutdown operations before the process terminates.

Comment: And Configure a Health Probe Endpoint: Define a health probe endpoint in your application that responds with a healthy status when the application is ready to receive traffic. Azure App Service can periodically send requests to this endpoint to check the health of your application. Once the health probe endpoint responds with a healthy status, Azure App Service will start routing traffic to your application.